# Get only the query string in current view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am setting the canonical URL for my Rails site which has many many subdomains that render the exact same content as the main domain.

I am adding this to the top of my layouts:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://cappedin.com#{url_for}" />`

Which makes sure Google crawlers know the definitive source to help my SEO.

The above code does not include the query string when one exists

I can `request.query_parameters` and then break that out into a string... but is there an easy way to just get the `?provider=233` query string out of requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just get the query string for your request, `request.query_string` returns everything but the '?'